# Purpose of dividing by 1 javascript

Tags: javascript, html, math

I was working on a simple programming exercise my teacher gave us, and I noticed several times that in Javascript, I have to divide a number by 1, otherwise it will return a ridiculous value. Any explanations?
I have a jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/TpNay/1/

`var widthrand=Math.floor(Math.random()*widthRange);
width=widthrand +  document.getElementById('width').value/1;`

If you look at line 22, and take out the divide by 1, and click generate, it will return ridiculous lengths
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It makes JavaScript type juggle forcing the value of `document.getElementById('width').value` to become numeric.

A better way to do it would be `parseInt(document.getElementById('width').value, 10)`

Comment: Specifically, the "ridiculous lengths" you mention are because the + sign is overloaded for strings, and so you see Javascript concatenating the two values instead of summing them when the second is a string.

Comment: don't forget to pass the second `radix` parameter to `parseInt`.

Comment: Why is `parseInt` "better"? Is just another way of accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: It's much clearer what you're trying to do and isn't "hackish" like dividing by 1.

Comment: parseInt() doesn't do the same thing _unless_ the string being converted contains nothing but digits.